Laravel Livewire test assertSet()
I often have problems with Livewire Tests and assertSet() and Model properties - for example:
->assertSet('model', Model::first())

throws a Failed asserting that two objects are equal error because the actual Object has an attributeCastCache or changes.
I always do a workaround and store the component in a variable.
$component = Livewire::test(Component::class);
$this->assertSame($component->model, Model::first());
Is there another way?

can you change to Model::class  and see the expected?

you mean ->assertSet('model', Model::class) ?
